# how to i deploy a contract from the backend server?

Tags: contract-deployment, nft, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I have a dapp that compiles a solidity smart contract in the backend server. I want the user to send a transaction that'll deploy the contract. Basically the user enters the name and the symbol as input in a form on the frontend. The backend server uses those as parameters and makes a NFT contract and the user deploys it by sending a transaction from their wallet.

How does that work, i am able to compile the contract in the backend but not able to figure out a way so that the user can deploy it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to pay for the deployment you have to return the compiled bytecode and prepare the transaction on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better make another contract, expose a function in the contract which deploys the target contract, and let users interact with this contract with their wallet directly in frontend.